# Solvability of a simple nonlocal elliptic equation.

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, elliptic-equations, fractional-calculus

I am looking for a theory to handle an elliptic equation with square root of Laplacian involved. Namely,
$$ (-\Delta)^{1/2} v(x) + c(x) v(x) = f(x),$$
with relevant boundary conditions. Here I can assume $c(x) > 0$ if necessary. Any result in 1-D periodic setting would be also helpful because that is what I have in mind for now. Any books or papers to look at? Thank you!

Comment: I'm assuming $(-\nabla^2)^{1/2}v(\mathbf{x})$ is supposed to mean $\sqrt{-\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{\partial^2v}{\partial {x_i}^2}\right)}$? Sorry, I'm not too familiar with operator notation.

Comment: @K.defaoite No. It's a pseudodifferential operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe have a look at

https://www.uni-due.de/imperia/md/images/mathematik/ruhr_pad/ruhrpad-2020-04.pdf

where existence and uniqueness of so called entropy solutions is shown to an equation involving the fractional Laplacian.
From a quick look I would say the equation dealt with in the upper paper is a little more involved, maybe it helps anyways.